# heroku scale web=1 returns "no such type as web"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scale

I'm trying to set up a staging server for a client who already has an app in production. Production is scaled up with 8 web dynos.

I created a staging app and pushed the code.  When I run:

```
heroku scale web=1 --app=myapp-staging
```

I get:

```
Scaling web processes... failed
!    No such type as web
```

The procfile is exactly the same in both cases. It's just two lines, and looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

On the app config, I've set $PORT to 80 and $RACK_ENV to 'production'. Rails is 3.2.8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be uppercase `Procfile`. If you do `heroku run bash` and check with `ls` is the file actually there?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple text file:  **Procfile**
with the following content: **`web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}`** for a playframework application or **`web: sh target/bin/webapp`** for a sample java web application.